# window.opener.doccument.getelementbyid() is not working when popup from iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am calling a popup from an iframe and when I click a button the popup should close and show a message in parent iframe.  I am using the javascript below

```
function ClosePopup() {
   var fRame = window.opener.document.getElementByID('lblMessage').innerHTML="testMessage"; 
   self.close();
}
```

However, when I execute this, an error is returned : `getelementbyid is null`.

How can I show a message in the parent iframe. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is the parent on the same domain as the iframe?

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. Check `getElementById` method spelling in your code (in your question `ID` is capitalized)

Comment: I suppose that `lblMessage` is server id of control whereas you need to use ClientID in javascript. Usually this ids different when Master page used

Answer (score 0):

To resolve issue from your question, fix `getElementById` method spelling. 
Regarding problem with null lblMessage value, you must use ClientID of server control if you want to perform any action on it in JavaScript. Server ID and ClientID of control are different in case when control placed in some NamingContainer parent control. The most often situation is when you use Master pages in your application.